# Why Identity.Name is null in webapi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have `webapi` application in dotnet 5, and I run it in the command: `dotnet run --project MyApi`, and it listens in port 5000/5001.

I want to use Windows authentication in my app.

When I access my endpoint to get the user, I get an error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is because `Identity.Name` is null.

The application can't able to resolve the user.

[image]

I did the following things to make it work - what is missing here?

The code looks like this:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
              options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
            });

        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable the windows authentication for the Kestrel, you should install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate NuGet package and use it instead of just using the IIS Scheme.

More details, you could refer to below codes:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate();

```
        services.AddControllers();
        
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }
```

Besides, please don't forget add the Authorize attribute for the controller, this is the reason why your identity name is null, since the controller is no need for authentication.

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
 services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    });
```

and **authentication** middleware before **authorization**

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

It should work.

Comment: I did but still the object `Name` is null.